# Nested OR with AND and IF - Excel

Tags: arrays, excel, conditional-statements

Simple question that I wasn't able to figure out. Trying to calculate counts and medians of arrays with a conditional that depends on numbers in two columns in Excel, as seen below.

=MEDIAN(IF(AND($D$3:$D$1216=1,OR($B$3:$B$1216=3,$B$3:$B$1216=6,$B$3:$B$1216=9,$B$3:$B$1216=12)),$M$3:$M$1216))

Please see above for the function, which I input as an array. All I'd like to do is scan Column D for all 1s and then 3/6/9/12 in Column B.

The function works but only returns zeroes for all relevant values in Column D, which I find strange.

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Is 0 in fact the most common element in `$M$3:$M$1216`? i.e., are a lot of those cells just blank?

When I keep the range large, but only enter a few values, I get the same result as you. When I shrink the range to something more manageable, and fill in the values, the function returns what I'd expect.

Also, here's a somewhat simpler syntax for the same result:

`=MEDIAN(($D$3:$D$5=1)*OR($B$3:$B$5=3,$B$3:$B$5=6,$B$3:$B$5=9,$B$3:$B$5=12)*($M$3:$M$5))`

Comment: Nope, none of those cells are blank. Very odd that a smaller range works, appreciate the simpler syntax

Comment: I assume you're entering it as an array formula, so that `{}`s appear around the formula in the viewer, yes? Does a simpler range work for you?

Comment: Yes I am so the brackets do show up. And no, it does not. But removing the and condition (so just having that or statement), works fine. Checked formatting of Column D and it was a number just like the others..

Comment: Hmm. The formula works as written on my machine. Maybe a workaround would be to create a new column that returns the value in B if and only if D=1, then use the working OR condition on that column?

Comment: Wow, surprised that it works. Beyond my Excel knowledge to understand how that can happen. That is a good workaround but in my case D would be changing, I just set it to 1 for ease of explanation.